# the meaning of 'two hoops" here

Tags: word-meaning

> On his second Monday morning the door to Jack Buggit’s office gaped.
>   Inside, Buggit himself, a cigarette behind his ear, leaning back in a
>   wooden chair and saying “hmm” on the telephone. He waved Quoyle in to
>   him **with two hoops of his right hand.**

*The Shipping News by Annie Proulx*

It sounds like Jack Buggit signals Quoyle to come in with his hand, but I don't get the meaning of **'two hoops**'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never before heard "hoop" used to refer to any hand gesture, but given that a hoop is a circular object, I picture Buggit sweeping his hand in a circular motion, as if pulling Quoyle in along with the surrounding air.